# I want to implement DevExpress Grid have issue to bind a save button

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, devexpress

**Demo**
https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/Widgetsgallery/Demo/DataGrid/RowEditingAndEditingEvents/NetCore/Light/

What I am trying to achieve is when user click on Edit it updates the row then when user click the save it should send the request to the action and update the database we are using Asp MVC Core the issue I am having is I don't know which custom Jquery function DevExtreme is bound the save button please check the code and I am also sharing the DevExpre URL

```
@using DevExtremeAspNetCoreApp1.Models

<h2>Home</h2>

@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<Order>()
                .ShowBorders(true)
                .DataSource(d => d.Mvc().Controller("Orders").LoadAction("Get").Key("OrderID"))
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.AddFor(m => m.OrderID);
                    columns.AddFor(m => m.OrderDate);
                    columns.AddFor(m => m.CustomerName);
                    columns.AddFor(m => m.ShipCountry);
                    columns.AddFor(m => m.ShipCity);
                })
                .Paging(p => p.PageSize(10))
                .Editing(editing =>
                {
                    editing.Mode(GridEditMode.Row);
                    editing.AllowAdding(true);
                    editing.AllowDeleting(true);
                    editing.AllowUpdating(true);
                }).OnRowUpdated(@<text> function(e) { logEvent("RowUpdated"); } </text>)
                                                .FilterRow(f => f.Visible(true))
                                                .HeaderFilter(f => f.Visible(true))
                                                .GroupPanel(p => p.Visible(true))
                                                .Grouping(g => g.AutoExpandAll(false))
                                                .RemoteOperations(true)
                                                .Summary(s => s
                                                    .TotalItems(totalItems =>
                                                    {
                                                        totalItems.AddFor(m => m.ShipCity).SummaryType(SummaryType.Count);
                                                    })
                                                    .GroupItems(groupItems =>
                                                    {
                                                        groupItems.Add().SummaryType(SummaryType.Count);
                                                    })
                                                )
)



<div id="data-grid-demo">
    @(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<Order>()
                        .ShowBorders(true)
                        .DataSource(d => d.Mvc().Controller("Orders").LoadAction("Get").Key("OrderID"))
                        .ID("gridContainer")
                        .ShowBorders(true)
                        .Paging(p => p.Enabled(false))
                        .Editing(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.Popup)
                           .AllowUpdating(true)
                           .Popup(p => p
                                .Title("Employee Info")
                                .ShowTitle(true)
                                .Width(700)
                                .Height(525)
                                .Position(pos => pos
                                    .My(HorizontalAlignment.Center, VerticalAlignment.Top)
                                    .At(HorizontalAlignment.Center, VerticalAlignment.Top)
                                    .Of(new JS("window"))
                                )
                           )
                           .Form(f => f.Items(items =>
                           {
                               items.AddGroup()
                                   .ColCount(2)
                                   .ColSpan(2)
                                   .Items(groupItems =>
                                   {
                                       groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.CustomerID);
                                       groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.CustomerName);
                                       groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.OrderDate);
                                       groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.OrderID);
                                       groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.ShipCity);
                                       groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.ShipCountry);

                                       groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.CustomerName)
                                           .ColSpan(2)
                                           .Editor(editor => editor.TextArea().Height(100));
                                   });

                               items.AddGroup()
                                   .Caption("Home Address")
                                   .ColCount(2)
                                   .ColSpan(2)
                                   .Items(groupItems =>
                                   {
                                       groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.CustomerID);
                                       groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.CustomerID);
                                   });
                           }))
                        )
                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.AddFor(m => m.CustomerID)
                                .Width(70);

                            columns.AddFor(m => m.CustomerName);

                            columns.AddFor(m => m.CustomerName);

                            columns.AddFor(m => m.CustomerName);

                            columns.AddFor(m => m.CustomerName)
                                .Width(170);

                            columns.AddFor(m => m.CustomerName);

                            columns.AddFor(m => m.CustomerName)
                                .Width(125)
                                .Lookup(lookup => lookup
                                    .DataSource(d => d.Mvc().Controller("DataGridStatesLookup").LoadAction("Get").Key("ID"))
                                    .DisplayExpr("Name")
                                    .ValueExpr("ID")
                                );

                            columns.AddFor(m => m.CustomerName)
                                .Visible(false);

                            columns.AddFor(m => m.CustomerName)
                                .Visible(false);
                        })
                        .DataSource(d => d.Mvc()
                            .Controller("DataGridEmployees")
                            .LoadAction("Get")
                            .UpdateAction("Put")
                            .Key("ID")
                        )
                        .DataSourceOptions(d => d.Filter("['ID', '<=' , 14]"))
    )
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating an action in your controller to handle the HttpPut event?

```cs
.DataSource(d => d.Mvc()
     .Controller("Order")
     .LoadAction("Get")
     .UpdateAction("Put") //Add an action
    .Key("OrderId")
)
```

Your action will send a **key** parameter and a **values** parameter to the action. You need to:

1. Get your order based on the key
2. Deserialize the Json
3. Update the items in your order
4. Return the order

The demo that you have linked does this same thing:

```cs
[HttpPut]
public IActionResult Put(int key, string values) {
    var employee = _data.Employees.First(a => a.ID == key);
    JsonConvert.PopulateObject(values, employee);

    if(!TryValidateModel(employee))
         return BadRequest(ModelState.GetFullErrorMessage());

    _data.SaveChanges();

    return Ok();
}
```